# OnTextChanged even not working as expected in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

I have a textbox in a gridview. The column template for the gridview binds data to the textbox. The original value will be called X. If I change the text in the textbox inside the grid view to Y the onTextChanged event will fire when I press a button. After I have changed the text to Y, and the event has fired, the event will continue to fire if each time i click the button. If I change the text to the orignal value, X, the onTextChanged event stops firing.

There are textboxes outside of the gridView. They all call onTextChanged as expected; When text is changed from what was there before.

How can I make the onTextChanged act like its expected instead of an onTextIsNotOrignalValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to enable ViewState for the text box on the grid view? I am not sure if you have to enable Viewstate on the gridview itself.

Comment: When i read your post i though that would have to be the issue. I explicitly set viewsate to true on the gridview and textboxes but ended up getting the same results. I'm sure it has to do with the state or the binding that is happening. Only when the text in the box matches the original binding will it not fire the event.

Comment: Do the text boxes only show up when you are editing a record in the grid view or do they show up there by default?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set AutoPostBack of Textbox to True?

Comment: I set the autoPostBack value to True in for the TextBox in the template of the grid view. It did not change the behavior on the page.

Comment: ok. What do you want to do? Because the OnTextChanged is fire when the Texbox lost the focus. [AutoPostBack of the Textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx)